# center a absolute positioned

Tags: css, html, center

I know how to center divs with  CSS easily using `position: relative;` and `margin:auto;` , but i have a div that is supposed to be in front of all the other divs - so I set `z-index: 1000;` and `position:absolute;` .   I can't figure out any other way to set this in front without `position: absolute;`  if i try relative then it will go below everything else to the bottom.  My question is how do I set this div that has `z-index: 1000; position: absolute;` to stay in the center?

I try `left: 20%;` which looks perfect , but when it is displayed on larger screens or much smaller screens obivously that percentage is not going to be the same.

Comment: Center both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. give a fixed % width and do the math to center:

`position:absolute;width:60%;left:20%` (`100%-60% = 40%` -->  `40% / 2 = 20%`)

2 . position the div using `position:absolute;text-align:center;`, and give the inner elements `position:relative;display:inline-block;`

Comment: No Problem, it can get tricky when you don't want to do a fixed % width, but need a fixed px width. If that happens, see #2 on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your div has a width and height and then 50% positioning with margins negative half of the size. E.g. a div 100px x 100px:

```
z-index: 1000; 
position: absolute;

top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
margin-top: -50px;
```

Comment: This is the best answer imho

Comment: This is the best solution, especially if the width of the elements to be centered is given in px.

Answer (score -1):

You can still use `z-index` on a `position:relative` div. Just make sure all other `z-index` objects also needs to have a declared position.

Comment: that would defeat the z-index , even though the high z-index is putting this div in front , it is going to be placed next to other divs , not on top - because of relative positioning